# Mysql join issues with only 2 tables using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having an issue with the mysql join.let me explain what tables I have got.

Table 1

```
rid        hid       email
1          501       10
1          502       20
2          501       30
4          8075      40
1          501       50
```

Table 2

```
rid        title     
1          pw1     
2          pw1     
3          pw2      
4          pw4
```

My code is like below

```
$allhids = array(501,502,8075); //all the unique hids

foreach($allhids as $k=>$v)
{
$getsubrows = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT table1.hid,table2.title,sum(table1.email) as totalqty 
              FROM `table1`,table2
              where table1.hid = ".$v."
              and table2.rid = table1.rid 
              group by table2.title ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  while($subrow = mysqli_fetch_array($getsubrows, MYSQLI_NUM))
  {
       echo $subrow[0]."----".$subrow[1]."----".$subrow[2]."<br>";      
  }
}
```

Now it outputs as

```
501----pw1----60  
501----pw2----30
502----pw1----20 
8075----pw4----40
```

Now I want it to be like this

```
501----pw1----60  
501----pw2----30
501----pw4----0
502----pw1----20
502----pw2----0
502----pw4----0 
8075----pw1----0
8075----pw2----0
8075----pw4----40
```

So I want to include the titles whose ids are not present in table 1 and if not present then it will show 0.

Actually for each hid there will be 3(pw1,pw2,pw4) rows always.If no emails then 0.

Any suggestion or hint is really appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you change ````sum(table1.email)```` to ````IFNULL(sum(table1.email),0)```` in your query?

Comment: Thanks. I tested with it but it's still now showing other titles as row.

Comment: I have added some extra info.

Comment: this is very bad designed. You should have one relation table in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate all the rows first, and then use `left join` to get the data:

```
SELECT h.hid, t2.title, coalesce(sum(t1.email), 0) as totalqty 
FROM (SELECT distinct hid FROM table1) h CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT distinct rid FROM table1) r LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.rid = r.rid LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON h.hid = t1.hid
group by h.hid, t2.title;
```

Note:  this doesn't include the `where` clause, which seems incompatible with the desired results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with it and got an sql error which says #1054 - Unknown column 't1.rid' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

In the `table2` you have two lines with `pw1` (1,2) so the first line of results will be 90 not 60.

Here is the query. Subquery `A` forms all possible variants for `hid,title` and subquery `B` counts sums then just `LEFT JOIN` them.

```
SELECT A.hid,
       A.title,
       ifnull(B.email_sum,0) as totalqty

FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.hid,
       t2.title
  FROM Table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
) as A
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT Table1.hid,
         Table2.title,
         SUM(Table1.email) as email_sum
    FROM Table1 
       JOIN Table2 on (Table1.rid=Table2.rid)
    GROUP BY Table1.hid, Table2.title
 ) as B
  on (A.hid=B.hid AND A.title=B.title)

ORDER BY A.Hid,A.Title
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/339aa/8)</kbd>

Comment: The value in the first result line comes from the two Table1.rid/Table1.hid combinations (1/501) and that is the first and the last line of Table1. And thus it is 60. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @OcasoProtal The first line is for the pair `501----pw1----` but in table2 there are two lines with `PW1` (1,2) so actually you should sum 3 lines from the Table1.